# Как получить адреса гиперссылок из ячеек Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, link

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице несколько ссылок, но когда я копирую то, что в ячейках, то получаю значения:

*38014960*

*38014980*

*38014740*

*38015080*

Как мне получить ссылки?

Answer (score 0):

Просто так (`Copy/Paste`) не получится. Но с помощью функции пользователя (`UDF`) можно.

Открыть проект `VBA` (`Alt+F11`). в общем модуле разместить функцию:

```
Function HyperGet(rRng As Range) As String
    With rRng
        If .Hyperlinks.Count Then
            HyperGet = .Hyperlinks(.Hyperlinks.Count).Address 'адрес присвоенной ссылки'  
        Else
            If Left$(.Formula, 10) = "=HYPERLINK" Then
                HyperGet = Mid$(Split(.Formula, ",")(0), 12) ' адрес ссылки из формулы'  
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

В ячейке, где нужно получить адрес гиперссылки, записать формулу:

```
=HyperGet(A2)
```

Вместо `A2` - ссылка на первую ячейку диапазона, из которого нужно получить гиперссылки. Протянуть формулу по строкам.